# parsedhtml doesnt respond anymore

Tags: html, powershell

So I'm trying to get some text from a website, and as soon as I try to return an object with ParsedHtml, powershell stops responding (even when I let it run in the background a few minutes it wont do anything anymore).
What can be the cause of that?

```
PS P:\> $url = "mywebsite"
PS P:\> $result = invoke-WebRequest $url
PS P:\> $result | Get-Member

TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
Dispose           Method     void Dispose(), void IDisposable.Dispose()
Equals            Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode       Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType           Method     type GetType()
ToString          Method     string ToString()
AllElements       Property               
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection AllElements {get;}
BaseResponse      Property   System.Net.WebResponse BaseResponse {get;set;}
Content           Property   string Content {get;}
Forms             Property           
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormObjectCollection Forms {get;}
Headers           Property           
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string] Headers {get;}
Images            Property   
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection Images {get;}
InputFields       Property   
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection InputFields {get;}
Links             Property       
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection Links {get;}
ParsedHtml        Property   mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 ParsedHtml {get;}
RawContent        Property   string RawContent {get;set;}
RawContentLength  Property   long RawContentLength {get;}
RawContentStream  Property   System.IO.MemoryStream RawContentStream {get;}
Scripts           Property       
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection Scripts {get;}
StatusCode        Property   int StatusCode {get;}
StatusDescription Property   string StatusDescription {get;}

PS P:\> $result.ParsedHtml | Get-Member
```

And then the programm freezes after last command.
A popup pops up asking me if its allowed to save cookies on my pc, but neither clicking yes nor no will help anything..
What can be the cause of this?

```
$result.RawContent
```

for example works just fine and prints out all of the html text, but has no getelementsby-Method, which I guess is in ParsedHtml, hence why I would need it..it works for example on youtube but on a specific site i want to check it freezes.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try adding the `-UseBasicParsing` switch on your `Invoke-WebRequest` call.

Comment: Just tried, the ParsedHtml doesnt exist in $result then anymore. Give missing object error when trying to access $result.ParsedHtml, also it doesnt appear when I use $result | Get-Member method anymore

Comment: Believe this is caused by the security settings in Internet Explorer. When it parses the HTML it uses IE, and also its security settings.

Comment: i try to work around now. any other way to get out specific words from a table on the website?

Comment: @btc ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

From [Invoke-WebRequest reference page on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-WebRequest?view=powershell-7):

> This parameter has been deprecated. Beginning with PowerShell 6.0.0,
> all Web requests use basic parsing only. This parameter is included
> for backwards compatibility only and any use of it has no effect on
> the operation of the cmdlet.

and a more detailed explanation from MS staff comment on
[PowerShell Github repository Issue #2867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2867#issuecomment-427519945):

> Windows PowerShell relied on Internet Explorer to parse the html.
> Since Internet Explorer wasn't available in most platforms we support
> with PowerShell Core 6 (nanoserver, Linux, macOS), it made sense to
> default to -UseBasicParsing. @MSAdministrator's proposal for
> ConvertFrom-Html is a better solution rather than marrying the parsing
> capability to the web cmdlets (like parsing a local html file).
> and later:
> Seems that the community has helped fill in this gap with modules on PowerShellGallery to specifically handle parsing html.

And today there does not seem to be a ConvertFrom-Html, so I guess your choices are: PowerShell Gallery modules that provide parsing, or a limited alternative follows. It looks like they won't give you the ParsedHTML property per se, but they do give you some traversable/structured content that *might* serve your purposes:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53878303/537243

In very, very limited circumstances you could try and make use of the way that "html is a subtype of xml", but xml parser will get confused and fail with a lot of syntax "deviations" permitted in html, so the source has to be very regular and very vanilla:

```
$webresponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://w3.org"
$xmldoc = [xml]$webresponse.Content
write-output $xmldoc.html.body.div[0].div.h1.span |select '#text'
```